# Iphone javascript defaults?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari

what are the javascript defaults for safari on iphone or ipad? I mean does safari have javascript turned on or off by default out of the box. 
If it is off, then is it possible to programmaticaly change that settings?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is enabled by default.

Just like on desktop browsers, you cannot change a user's JavaScript on/off setting on an iPad, iPhone or iPod touch.

Comment: Cool. Do you know about android and blackberry also?

Comment: @user194076: I'm not 100% sure, but I'm confident it's the same for both.

Comment: Just got a brand new iPad (6th gen, 2018 with iOS 11.3) and to my horror... Javascript is disabled by default in Safari. Kind of unbelievable. Think of all the newbies out there coming to your website using default Safari and not be able to f-all. I suppose Apple is forcing you to do super semantic design and wants you to prompt users to enable JS.