# Angular 5 app doesn't render in safari mobile browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I have a simple angular 5 application that uploads an image to my web server. This angular 5 app works perfectly in chrome(mobile/desktop) and only Safari desktop version. but when I access it from my iPhone using Safari as a web browser, it does not render.....to be able to work I have to enable JS:

[image]

When I make this configuration in IOS the web application works without problems...then my question is....what can I do so that my angular web app be rendered in mobile safari, without having to make this configuration in IOS?

Angular Code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" lang="es" (change)="onFileChange($event)">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFileLang">{{fileName}}</label>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent{
  title = 'app';
  fileName:string;
  base64:string;

  constructor(private imageService: ImageService) {
  }

  onFileChange(event) {
    let image:File = event.target.files[0];
    this.base64=image.name;
    this.imageService.saveImage(image).subscribe();
  }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? I seems you are saying that Safari on iOS has JS disabled, but you expect a JS application to work anyway. It seems the answer is to enable JS in Safari iOS. What am I missing?

Comment: The problem is that this option is disabled by default in IOS, then every user who wants to use my application must enable javascript. This is something that can cause my application not to be used, because they may think it does not work, so the idea is to prevent each user from having to do this ... how could he do it?

Comment: show a message in case of js not being enabled saying they have to enable it?

Comment: How could I do something like that?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

Answer (score 0):

An Angular app (in Typescript) is transpiled in Javascript, so it will not work until JavaScript is enabled.

It looks like [the default value of this setting is "enabled"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822857/iphone-javascript-defaults) so don't worry about your visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the IOS version (11.4.1) that I have, because when you've never manipulated it, the button looks like it's disabled, but it's actually active ... but when you manipulate it, it actually shows the status button ... that is, active or inactive...which means that JS is active by default in IOS, but it is shown as inactive

[See more details](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8476294)